# aR->ggplot2->Graphing weekly timeserie data->multiple years/states->with confidence intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, confidence-interval

Raw Data:
[Here is the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/129uAnhkYGWUhCEyIp5YK4dKAvWhND9ax2qcXOQb2i0Q/edit?usp=sharing)

I have 50 states, weekly data from 1997 to current that look like this:

```
structure(list(date = c("1/1/2011", "1/8/2011", "1/15/2011", 
"1/22/2011", "1/29/2011", "2/5/2011", "2/12/2011", "2/19/2011", 
"2/26/2011", "3/5/2011", "3/12/2011", "3/19/2011", "3/26/2011", 
"4/2/2011", "4/9/2011"), CT = c(8593L, 14629L, 8084L, 6986L, 
6050L, 6368L, 5408L, 5416L, 6098L, 5260L, 4428L, 3823L, 3808L, 
4366L, 4697L), MA = c(13656L, 14779L, 9462L, 8565L, 9575L, 8548L, 
9248L, 7569L, 11373L, 8891L, 7113L, 6775L, 4524L, 7099L, 7390L
), ME = c(2521L, 3811L, 3239L, 2306L, 2381L, 2000L, 1878L, 1745L, 
1582L, 2008L, 1887L, 1676L, 1707L, 1898L, 1843L), NH = c(3155L, 
2892L, 1983L, 1961L, 1948L, 1596L, 1533L, 1534L, 1905L, 1819L, 
1434L, 1366L, 1288L, 1376L, 1477L), RI = c(3446L, 3159L, 2428L, 
2221L, 2010L, 1891L, 2351L, 2107L, 2883L, 1763L, 1595L, 1434L, 
1094L, 1154L, 1496L), VT = c(2173L, 1547L, 946L, 838L, 883L, 
838L, 704L, 890L, 1230L, 761L, 1019L, 854L, 830L, 848L, 1205L
), NJ = c(18871L, 21451L, 16872L, 15175L, 12138L, 13015L, 12777L, 
10372L, 10528L, 10036L, 9582L, 8551L, 9477L, 9141L, 9750L), NY = c(37620L, 
61983L, 33269L, 27656L, 28151L, 26433L, 26553L, 22283L, 20990L, 
38916L, 21999L, 20928L, 20657L, 21008L, 24132L), PR = c(2961L, 
2437L, 2123L, 3423L, 4364L, 4525L, 4088L, 3765L, 3181L, 2857L, 
3366L, 2985L, 2730L, 2382L, 2720L)), .Names = c("date", "CT", 
"MA", "ME", "NH", "RI", "VT", "NJ", "NY", "PR"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like make annual graphs for each states for the past 5 years.  And this is what I have managed so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
require(plotly)

df <- read_csv('icclaims.csv') %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = '%m/%e/%Y'),
         doy = as.numeric(format(date, '%j')),
         Year = as.factor(year(date))) %>%
  gather(key = 'state', value = 'claims', -date, -doy, -Year) %>%
  arrange(date)

df %>%
  filter(state %in% c('CA', 'MA')) %>%
  # Make sample plot
  ggplot(aes(x = doy, y = claims, group = Year, colour = Year)) +
  geom_path() + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ state, ncol = 1) +
  geom_smooth(span = 1, level=.99) +  #THANKS TO @JIMBOU
  theme_bw()
```

Here is what the output look like:
[image]

The final aim is to see if a new weekly data from a particular state is outside of the 99% confidence interval of that state, base on how ever long I decide to look into the past.

The remaining problem is how to get geom_smooth() to use all the years of the data to calculate the confidence interval rather than just a single year.  In short, I want to print year by year of the last 5 years, but showing the confidence interval for whole range of the data from 1997 to 2017.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: please use `dput()` to show some data.

Comment: @Jimbou I don't know what dput() will do, but I have attached a link to the data  [here on google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/129uAnhkYGWUhCEyIp5YK4dKAvWhND9ax2qcXOQb2i0Q/edit#gid=643523233)

Comment: Please do not use links. There are many reasons against their usage. Copy&paste the output of `dput(df[1:15,1:7])`for instance.

Comment: @Jimbou I have done as you requested.

Comment: Something like this? `library(reshape2);
dl <- melt(d);
dl$date2 <- as.POSIXct(dl$date, format ="%m/%d/%Y");
ggplot(dl, aes(date2,value)) + geom_line(aes(color=variable)) + geom_smooth()`

Comment: @Jimbou I cannot get your code to run, I think you meant `dl <- melt(df);`  and then it threw all kind of errors.  But I don't think there is a confident interval any where in your code to help answer my question.

Comment: I mean `melt(your_data)`. Try your example data. Just save the `dput()`  in a data.frame like this `your_data <- dput(...`. Then use the code above. The  `geom_smooth()` function plots a 95% CI per default.

Comment: @Jimbou, You have provided 90% of the solution to my question.  If you can help with the last bit, and put your solution as a response instead of a comment so I can accept your solution as the answer.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simple trick is to put the factor only within the point/path function. Your data is saved in `d` and I use `melt()` to transform the data in the long format.

```
library(reshape2); 
dl <- melt(d[,1:3])
# the date object
dl$date2 <- as.Date(dl$date, format = '%m/%e/%Y')

# add a second year 
dl2 <- dl 
dl2$date2 <- dl2$date2 + 365
dl2$value <- dl2$value + 10000
dl <- rbind(dl, dl2)

# Your x value Doy and the grouping factor
dl$Doy <- as.numeric(as.character(format(dl$date2, format="%j")))
dl$Year <- as.factor(format(dl$date2, format="%Y"))

# the plot
ggplot(dl, aes(Doy,value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Year)) + geom_path(aes(color=Year)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, ncol = 1) +
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]